# How to manage Tcl packages, considering that pkg_mkindex is deprecated?

Tags: tcl

I was surprised to read, that pkg_mkindex is deprecated (http://wiki.tcl.tk/3388) and even dangerous (http://wiki.tcl.tk/3382).

Now, 'deprecated' means "has been superseded by a new, better method, and the old one should not be used for new projects anymore".

However, the only alternative suggestion I came accross, was to create the pkgIndex.tcl file by hand, which doesn't look to me like an advance in package creation.

So, a question to experienced Tcl developers: How do you, then, manage the packages, if pkg_mkindex is something which should not be used anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improved solution is AFAICT discussed for Tcl 9. (Note that it's not *officially* deprecated.)

Some people want to deprecate it, again AFAICT, partly because it uses a fairly naïve method (which isn't *always* a bad thing), and partly because nowadays libraries need a lot more than just sorting out what files to `source` to be properly installed.

It is still useful for amateur-level package management: as long as you are indexing straight, simple Tcl scripts and avoiding indexing the directory from which you are calling `pkg_mkIndex`, it will do the job.

(If you are able to write libraries that are more sophisticated than `pkg_mkIndex` can handle, providing a hand-written index file is a breeze. But there should probably still be an updated tool available.)

ETA: my personal solution (subject to change, I tinker with my setup every few months) is to have library files that I edit often (which is most of them) in a sister directory to my work directories. In every work directory I have scriptlets that do stuff like run the test suite, create a session.vim file on the fly and start up gVim, and revision control my files. All these scriptlets source a mini-scriptlet that indexes the library directory and adds it to `auto_path`. The library files are just .tcl files with a `package provide` in them. Those few libraries that are 'done' I rewrite as modules and copy into my `C:\Tcl\lib\tcl8\8.6` directory.

Documentation: [auto_path](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [pkg_mkIndex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/pkgMkIndex.htm)

Comment: For single file packages there are already the Tcl modules introduced with 8.5, which do not need any pkgIndex.tcl file.

Comment: @schlenk: good point. Module management, while simple, needs to be further simplified, though.

Comment: Agreed, the management of modules isn't perfect yet, and the lack of a public open repository (besides the ActiveState teapot), is a bit unfortunate too. But at least it isn't a train wreck like python packaging, which changes every few months. One major lacking thing is any form of dependency management for packages and modules.

Comment: My solution is to never use pkg_mkindex from *within* my application, but having a Tcl script (residing in my $HOME/bin), which traverses the project tree and invokes pkg_mkindex on every directory. This should be safe, then, isn't it?

Comment: @user1934428: um, insufficient data. It's not a problem in itself to call `pkg_mkIndex` from your application, as long as you don't index the directory where the script that calls `pkg_mkIndex` resides (it's just an unbounded recursion issue). Is it really useful to index *every* directory in your project tree? To benefit from that, you then need to put those directories in your library path. (Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly.) Added my own setup for comparison.

Comment: Yes, it is ensured that the indexing script is not indexed. I am aware of this. As for the TCLLIBPATH, I don't need every indexed directory, because it is sufficient to have the top directory of a directory tree in TCLLIBPATH. The other ones are found from this automatically.

Comment: @user1934428: yes, but do you really need to index every directory of your project tree and then have them all as library directories? It sounds a bit under-specific. If you collect files that are used as libraries in one place and only put that directory in the library path it will be a heck of a lot easier to figure out dependencies later.

Comment: The `dir` in the `pkgIndex.tcl` scripts isn't a global variable; the scripts are evaluated in a local context.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Oh! I completely misunderstood that part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For most package authors, running it *once* when you're starting out to write the package isn't a problem at all. But the script it generates (in `pkgIndex.tcl`) is pretty simple, and you can do better by adjusting that script to meet your own real requirements.

Luckily, if you're using Tcl 8.5 or later, you can use `apply` to simplify things a lot. That means you can generate your script like this:

```
### Read this as if it is:
#### package ifneeded $pkg $version [list apply {dir $thescript} $dir]
package ifneeded MyFunkyPackage 1.2.3 [list apply {dir {
    # Work out the right binary library name
    switch $tcl_platform(platform) {
        windows { set lib MFP123.DLL }
        default { set lib libMFP.1.2.3[info sharedlibextension] }
    }
    load [file join $dir $lib] MFP
    # Source a bunch of scripts with their encodings forced to UTF-8
    foreach script [glob -directory $dir MFP*.tcl] {
        source -encoding utf-8 $script
    }
}} $dir]
```

OK, that's a *very* fancy package definition script, but it would be awkward to do any other way — constructing the script in a double quoted string would be painful and probably error-prone too — and yet is trivial here because you've got local variables, structured programming constructs, the works. (You could also do it by generating the correct thing during `configure`, assuming you're following the TEA model, but that requires that you're happy hacking around with autoconf, which definitely isn't for all people…)